# How to send/receive HashMap to/from database using Java and JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, hashmap

A colleague has configured Java and MySQL to {send/receive} = [IN/OUT] parameters as `HashMap` and returns the result as `HashMap`.

Is it possible or any third party package required to configure?

```
public void sendValuesTODatabase(String user_id, String userName) {          
    HashMap hm1 = new HashMap();
    hm1.put("1", user_id);       // Parameters according to the Type
    hm1.put("2", username);


    int nooftable = 3;           /* represents number of select statements used in Stored           
                                    Procedure */

    Vector vCols = new Vector();
    vCols.addElement("1");       // One Column used for selection in Mysql select query 1
    vCols.addElement("2");       // Two Column used for selection in Mysql select query 2
    vCols.addElement("1");       // one Column used for selection in Mysql select query 3

    BlobValues bls = new BlobValues();
    HashMap hmap = (HashMap)bls.getGeneric(hm1,"DB_SCHEMA_NAME.SP_PACKAGE_NAME.PROCEDURE_NAME", 
                    nooftable, vCols);

    HashMap dBResult1 = (HashMap)hmap.get("GENERICJAVA1"); // Select stmt result1 in HashMap
    HashMap dBResult2 = (HashMap)hmap.get("GENERICJAVA2"); // Select stmt result2 in HashMap
    HashMap dBResult3 = (HashMap)hmap.get("GENERICJAVA3"); // Select stmt result3 in HashMap
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Framework offers a solution for this scenario.

We can use org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure or org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall class and pass the input parameter Map to its execute() method.

It returns the output parameter Map which you can iterate.

Below is example of StoredProcedure Class.

```
@Component
public class ItemInsert extends StoredProcedure {
public static final String SPROC_NAME = "schema.oracle_pkg.proc_name";
public static final String INPUT_PARAM = "input_prm_name";
public static final String OUPUT_PARAM = "output_prm_name";

@Inject
public ItemInsert(DataSource ds) {
super(ds, SPROC_NAME);
declareParameter(new SqlParameter(INPUT_PARAM, Types.VARCHAR));
declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(OUTPUT_PARAM, Types.NUMERIC));
compile();
}

public Item insert(Item item)
  throws DataAccessException {
Map<String, Object> inputs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
inputs.put(INPUT_PARAM, item.getSomething());
Map<String, Object> output = super.execute(inputs);
Object newId = output.get(OUTPUT_PARAM);
if (newId != null) {
  item.setId(Long.parseLong(newId.toString()));
}
return item;
}
```

Example of SimpleJdbcCall can be found at http://www.pretechsol.com/2014/04/how-to-call-stored-procedure-using.html#.VAtktsWSw1I

```
    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(template)
    .withProcedureName("customerDetails");
    Map<String, Object> inParamMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    inParamMap.put("id", 1);
    SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParamMap);
    Map<String, Object> simpleJdbcCallResult = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
    System.out.println(simpleJdbcCallResult);
```